# Error: Expression must have a constant value, when variable is constant?

Tags: c++

I have the following three lines of code in a C++ program:

```
cin >> size;
const int arrsize = size;

int inBoard[arrsize][arrsize];
```

VS Express is giving me the following error: `Error: expression must have a constant value` On the final line, specifically at the two mentions of `arrsize`. I don't understand this because I declared `arrsize` as a `const`? What is the problem here, and how can I avoid it?

Comment: It needs to be a compile-time constant.

Comment: So how can I create an array of a size determined by the user at runtime?

Comment: By using dynamic allocation via the `new` operator.

Comment: @user2356560 By creating it at runtime instead of compile time. (Btw, if it's not homework, I'd recommend using a `vector` for simplicity)

Comment: By using `std::vector`.

Comment: By using a standard container, like `std::vector`, or a class wrapping a 1D one and giving 2D semantics. Screw `new[]` 1000 times.

Comment: don't use int arrays for that type of array. Use a vector. This low-level stuff is not funny at all..

Comment: This is allowed in C99. But it is not legal C++ Code. I would recommend to use a proper container unless you really need built in arrays.

Comment: @MarioA.CorcheroJiménez, FWIW, it's legal in upcoming C++14 as well.

Comment: @chris: First they have to implement the C++11 standard ^^

Comment: @ultima_rat0, Well, GCC 4.9.0 is doing a fair job of C++14 so far, and 4.8.1 supposedly has finished all major C++11 features. Clang should be just about done with C++11 soon as well.

Comment: I declare you to be a fish.  Are you going to swim away/

Comment: @chris: Sounds good, but I got some issues with the standard libraries of C++11, mainly the thread-related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create an array on the stack like that using `arrsize` as the size because it is not constant during compile time. The value of `arrsize` will depend on `size`, which happens to acquire its value during run-time.

Solutions:

- Use an `std::vector<std::vector<int> >`
- Allocate your own 2D array with `operator new[]` (Not recommended. Seriously.)

Comment: Hmm, are vectors analagous to ArrayLists in Java?

Comment: @user2356560, They're pretty close, yes.

Comment: @0x499602D2 for the same reason he can't use a regular array - he doesn't know the size?

Comment: Or just push_back(...), looks more like oop.

Comment: This answer mixes up `const` and constant expressions. It's perfectly fine to assign `size` to `arrsize`. It doesn't matter about whether they are `const` or not. What matter is that `arrsize` is not a constant expression.

Comment: @sftrabbit I think I worded it better now.